# Bluetooth Low Energy in Android apps

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm trying to implement a BLE connection between android device and another device with BLE part(which is custom-built). However the message transmitting often went wrong when I tried to write a shake-hand string "234" to the device. As the official samples given by google is too general for me, I wonder if any of u has the experience on BLE connection and transmitting, pls offer some help, also some sample code will be nice too. Many thx.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Android must act as a Central. A [good example code is on GitHub](https://github.com/StevenRudenko/BleTISensorTag) illustrates how to connect to the TI KeyFob peripheral. It uses the 4.3 Android BTLE API. The gist of the Bluetooth communication is in `BluetoothLeService.java`

Comment: Hey @barbazoo- can you please assist me ,how we can scan the BLE device .Actually I have gone through the sample api provided by [developer android](http://developer.android.com/samples/BluetoothLeGatt/src/com.example.android.bluetoothlegatt/DeviceScanActivity.html) and also by GITHUB but unable to get any output,not even able to get the scan result.

Comment: First I recommend an app to test your hardware - for example Nordic's NRF Master Control app in the Google Play store. Bluetooth LE Scanner by Alexandros Schillings is also good. Once your phone is proved to be OK, move on to testing through the API.

Comment: Android can also act as a peripheral. (This may not have been true in 2013 when this answer was written). I have working code for Android acting as either a central or a peripheral.